# Android: Version selection

Tags: java, android

I want to develop an app for Android, but I know there are many different Android versions and, for example, I can't use the fragments in 2.x. So I want to know if I can program a "version selection", so that the app takes another code or another folder with code, if the Android version is less than 3?

Comment: actually, you can use fragments starting from Android 1.6 (API 4). Take a look at v4 support library.

Comment: You can do a version selecter; its just an awfull programming practice. Welcome to Android Development :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to provide different versions of your application to achieve the goal. Instead, make separate classes which contain the code which is supposed to run on higher version of the  Android OS, and you call the methods in them after a check:

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
     // Use the class
 }
```

Also, keep in mind that you have [compatibility libraries](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html) which provide most of the features you need on older devices. There is a library for Android 1.6+ and Android 2.1+, it is now safe to use both because the market share of devices earlier than Android 2.3 is negligible. The features these libraries provide include fragments, loaders, action bar, some layouts and other nice things, so in practice you shouldn't have to rely much on compatibility classes I described in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
int version = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (version >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO){

}
else if (version == 16) {

}
else {

}
```

For more information, see

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html

Comment: +1 But you should use constant variables as opposed to just typing in 16

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't do such version selector, which will select different .apk depending on the version.

However, if you want to use `Fragments` in Android 2.x you can do it using [Support Library v4](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v4).